# How to change src with onclick?

Tags: javascript, onclick, src

How change the `src` of a image with user input `src` ?
Here is my current JS code ↓

```
function prmpt () {
  var source = prompt ("Enter Image Source ↓")
}
var image = document.getElementById("img"); function changeColor() 
{ if (image.getAttribute('src') == "https://api.sololearn.com/Uploads/Avatars/3401170.jpg") { image.src = source; } 
else { image.src = "https://api.sololearn.com/Uploads/Avatars/3401170.jpg"; } }
```

Comment: Call the below function on an input of the image source, like onblur. Assign an id to your image for which the image needs to be changed function imageChanger(newimage) {
        document.getElementById("img").src=newimage;
    }

Comment: @user8271644 I can't understand please give me code !

Comment: Posted as an answer\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the below function on an input of the image source, like onblur. Assign an id to your image for which the image needs to be changed

```
function imageChanger(newimage) { 
document.getElementById("img").src=newimage; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you prefer:

`const changeImg = (newImg) => document.getElementById("img").src = newImg`